# Cubemen Is not starting

Tags: steam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I report bugs/problems with Valve’s Steam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236773/where-do-i-report-bugs-problems-with-valves-steam)

I bought Cubemen from steam today and installed it, but when I click Play, nothing happens. It says preparing to start and then nothing. I run Ubuntu 12.10 please help me.